# C# how to write multiple lines in a text file?

Tags: c#, file, text, lines

I am trying to press a button that takes the text from textbox4 and textbox5 to write it to a text file. BUT when I press it again to add new info to the text file it just replaces the old text in with the new. How do I get it to write another line below the first one each time I press the button?

This is the code I have so far

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            xuidspath = @"c:\xuids.txt";
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = textBox4.Text;
            lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox5.Text);
            listXuid.Items.Add(lvi);
            TextWriter xuids = new StreamWriter(xuidspath);
            xuids.WriteLine(textBox4.Text + "-" + textBox5.Text);
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            xuids.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be sure to include at least one language tag so your question can easily be found by those able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file for append.

```
FileStream xuids = new FileStream(xuidspath, FileMode.Append);
```

Answer (score 4):

just use StringBuilder class and File.WriteXXX methods.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(textBox.Text + " " + textbox2.Text);

File.WriteAllText("c:\xuids.txt",sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the original problem unless the StringBuilder itself is loaded with the file contents before appending a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use an overload:

```
public StreamWriter(string path, bool append);
```

i.e

```
TextWriter xuids = new StreamWriter(xuidspath,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
TextWriter xuids = new StreamWriter(xuidspath);
```

To:

```
TextWriter xuids = new StreamWriter(xuidspath, true);
```

The second parameter is append. From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) :

> Determines whether data is to be appended to the file. If the file
>   exists and append is false, the file is overwritten. If the file
>   exists and append is true, the data is appended to the file.
>   Otherwise, a new file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple string[]

Example:

```
string[] multiplelines = { "one", "two", "three" };
File.WriteAllLines("path", multiplelines);
```

Simple as that!

Answer (score -1):

```
RichTextBox rch = new RichTextBox();
rch.Text = cmn;
foreach (string l in rch.Lines)
    strw.WriteLine(l);
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.