# c# how save data in txt file in 1st line area always?

Tags: c#, save, streamreader, streamwriter, savefiledialog

I am want saving data in my txt file area but when I am try my below code then it's going saving in my txt file all line end area.

Actually my file available more then 4000 line so I am always want new line going saving first line area.

Please help me how I am saving data in first line area always.

below code only saving all line after mean end the area but I am want start line area going saving data.

```
string myFile = @"C:\\live\\dadata.txt";
StreamReader osr = new StreamReader(myFile);
string myText = osr.ReadToEnd();
osr.Close();
osr.Dispose();
StreamWriter osw = new StreamWriter(myFile);
osw.Write(myText + Environment.NewLine + workd.Text);
osw.Close();
osw.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can you please state your question more clearly?  I'm having a hard time following what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: think he is saying that his file saves all on 1 line and wants it to do a new line each time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315921/c-sharp-save-to-multiple-lines-in-a-text-file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236584/c-sharp-how-to-write-multiple-lines-in-a-text-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prepend a header in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511628/how-to-prepend-a-header-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is the Seek function of the StreamWriter to set the position of the cursor.  An example of how that might work is below.

```
'set the file pointer to the start of the file
  streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(offset:=0, _ 
        origin:=SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

I got the above from [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25932&seqNum=4). There are many places you can learn about Seek though.

I haven't personally tried it, but I have used Seek before in different languages, and seek is what you want, now you just need the specific syntax in the language of your choice.